# innerHTML and a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, innerhtml

```
function startMatch(deck, dealer, player){
    var dealerX = document.querySelector('#player:first-child span').innerHTML
    var playerX = document.querySelector('#player:last-child span').innerHTML
    dealer.push(drawCard(deck))
    player.push(drawCard(deck))
    dealerX = dealer
    playerX = player
    console.log(dealerX)
}
```

deck is an array of couple numbers
dealer and player are some empty global arrays
The problem is it logs the correct value of "dealerX" but it does not replace it in the HTML, if i use `document.querySelector('#player:first-child span').innerHTML = dealer`it works just fine but that is not what im looking for. thank you.

Comment: What is `dealerX = dealer` supposed to do?  `dealer` and `player` look like arrays (although can't really tell for sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because

```
var dealerX = document.querySelector('#player:first-child span').innerHTML
```

Doesn't create a reference to the element `#player`, it creates a variable with the contents of `#player`. So you will have to use

```
document.querySelector('#player:first-child span').innerHTML = dealer
document.querySelector('#player:last-child span').innerHTML = player
```

Comment: No, this is the only pure JS way